# Git Hosting for WordPress SVN Plugin Repository

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, git, svn, github

I'm setting up my first WordPress plugin on the [WordPress.org Plugin Site](https://wordpress.org/plugins/).  Behind the scenes, developers add plugins to this site via an SVN repository.

Is the any tooling (supported by Automattic and/or third party) that would allow me to seamlessly manage this svn repository via git and/or GitHub?  i.e. I'd like my "source of truth" for a Plugin's source to be GitHub, and for me to hit a button and/or run a cron script and have the plugin automatically moved into WordPress's svn repository with the right folder/tag/branch structure.

Comment: There are tools out there, but recommendations are offtopic here, you need to be able to mark an answer as the canonical definitive correct answer, that's not possible with recomendation questions which are very specific to you and quickly become out of date

Comment: @TomJNowell Not contesting the close, as you're the moderator and its your calls that define these things for a StackExchange site — but based on my experience in other StackExchange communities I'd argue that a vendor (Automattic) provided solution, or tooling that's so heavily used/ubiquitous that it's a de-facto standard are "canonical enough" and an answer thread that lists these tools still makes the internet a better place (the original "criteria 0" for Stack Overflow answers/questions). If the close-by-default policy ever comes up for review, please consider the above. Best wishes!

Comment: I'm also an Automattician, we don't make WordPress, the WordPress community does. Automattic runs WordPress.com the service, but has no direct control of WordPress.org and the opensource project. Having said that there's nothing stopping me personally contributing, and some people have dual roles, but the current lead is actually employed by 10up

Comment: @TomJNowell Fair distinction -- if you replace "vendor" with "platform steward" I'm still conformable with my suggestion :) Best wishes!